# upload image to ckeditor in laravel Incorrect server response

Tags: ckeditor, laravel-5.6

i am trying to upload image through ckeditor 4 
[image]

when i press send it the server
getting this Error `Incorrect Server Response`

here is my controller

```
public function mediauploadpost(Request $request){
    $CKEditor = $request->input('CKEditor');
    $funcNum  = $request->input('CKEditorFuncNum');
    $message  = $url = '';
    if (Input::hasFile('upload')) {
        $file = Input::file('upload');
        if ($file->isValid()) {
            $filename =rand(1000,9999).$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/wysiwyg/', $filename);
            $url = url('wysiwyg/' . $filename);
        } else {
            $message = 'An error occurred while uploading the file.';
        }
    } else {
        $message = 'No file uploaded.';
    }
    return '<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('.$funcNum.', "'.$url.'", "'.$message.'")</script>';
}
```

Comment: After file uploaded return this response to ckeditor:

` return response()->json([ 'fileName' => $filename, 'uploaded' => true, 'url' => $url ]);`

Answer (score 17):

I had this same issue recently, and the solution was to add this line to my `ckeditor-config.js` file:

```
config.filebrowserUploadMethod = 'form';
```

Comment: Solved this issue for me for CKEditor v4.20

Answer (score 3):

If you are using java as your backend server: return string response:

```
 "{\n " +
 "    \"uploaded\": 1,\n" +
 "    \"fileName\": \"foo.jpg\",\n" +
 "    \"url\": \"/files/foo.jpg\"\n" +
 "}"
```

See this [link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_upload.html) fro more information.
Also remember to to have annotation: `produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE` over your rest API.

Comment: I've checked via developer tools the example [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/image.html) and they use same response @suvriti-gandhi said. Here is the code I used in Laravel: `return response()->json([
         'fileName' => $filename,
         'uploaded' => true,
         'url' => $url,
     ]);`

Answer (score 2):

Remove this one

```
$res = "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" .$funcNum.  "," . $url . "," .$message. ")</script>"
```

Use this code in your return .

```
return response()->json([ 'fileName' => 'your file name put here', 'uploaded' => false, 'url' => $url, ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" .$funcNum.  "," . $url . "," .$message. ")</script>"

return response()->json(['data' => $res]);
```

Comment: While this may solve the question, a more comprehensive answer would be to explain what the error was and how this solution fixes that.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for replying me but its not working i found 
`$CKEditor = $request->input('CKEditor');` and `$funcNum  = $request->input('CKEditorFuncNum');` both request coming null how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

set the these propertis in your file

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('textarea_id',{
      filebrowserUploadUrl:"upload.php",
      filebrowserUploadMethod: "form"
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 7

```
CKEDITOR.replace('body', {
    filebrowserUploadUrl:'/admin/general-topic/images', // Route
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl:'/admin/general-topic/images', // File location
    filebrowserUploadMethod: "form"
})
```